Importing custom dimensions from Google Tag Manager data layer to GA4 for web app
We have a web app and are using GA4 for product analytics, have set up a container on Google Tag Manager and have linked it to our GA4 instance. We want to send additional user property data to GA4. For example, we can focus on the user type. We currently have this data in the Google Tag Manager data layer, and my problem is importing this into GA4.
Below in the picture you can see that I have tried various ways of having this field appearing in the data layer. EG, as a Data Layer Variable and Google Tag: Event Settings variable
Methods of incorporating value in data layer
My next step was to go to the tag settings, and add the Google Tag: Event Settings variable in shared event settings as follows, and publishing the tag. I have tried this both with:

Tag type: Google Tag
Changing the tag type to: GA4 Event Tag, having these user details in the User Properties section

Shared event settings
However, when trying to set this as a custom dimension in GA, the user type dimension does not appear to flow through and does not appear in the drop down
GA custom dimension screen
Are there any steps I'm missing, or any incorrect parameters that have been input along the way to cause this?

There's a mismatch in naming between what you're sending as parameter (userId) and what custom dimension you're creating (user_id).
I'd recommend changing the parameter name in shared event settings to user_id.
Once you do that, there's no need to register a user-scoped custom dimension for it, as user_id is a known field in GA4.
It is also recommended not to use user_id as custom dimension since it has a high cardinality.
